# Uploading images on Server using Servlet, AJAX and JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

Been searching all day and still can't find an answer, so I'm here 
(I'm new to Servlet programming)

I've got a form like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return performUpload()">
 <input type="text" id="upload-name" name="upload-name" required="required" />
 <input type="text" id="upload-address" name="upload-addres" required="required" />
 <input type="file" id="upload-file" name="upload-file" required="required" />
</form>
```

I want to use the `google.maps.Geocode` in the JS function before sending the data to `/UploadServlet` (need to register latitude/longitude on the server)
I'm trying to use `XMLHttpRequest` to send the data, something like this

```
//[some jquery to access form values]
var formdata=new FormData();
formdata.append("img",file);
formdata.append("upload-name",name);
//[other appends] 

var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //some code here (alert to confirm upload)
   }
};  
xhttp.open("POST","UploadServlet",true);
xhttp.send(formdata);
```

Now, how can I access all these parameters from the Servlet?
How can I upload the image on the server and use the other parameters for my needs?

I've found this code on the internet

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
      response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //String saveDir = ?
    //here I'd need to use one of the parameters i've passed through the 
     //  ajax request;

    // gets absolute path of the web application
    String appPath=getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"\\images";

    // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
    String savePath = appPath + File.separator + saveDir;


    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {

        String fileName = extractFileName(part);
        //refines the fileName in case it is an absolute path
        fileName = new File(fileName).getName();
        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
    }
}

private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Which works pretty good and is able to upload the image wherever I want using a form with only one input field of type "file" and without passing through JS/AJAX but using

```
      <form action=".." >
```

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to "adapt" this code to my needs (still don't understand how `request.getParts()` works )

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance